# KeystoneJS - stuck on login page

Tags: keystonejs

I recently started working with KeystoneJS, walked away for a week, and now I can't log back into my admin dashboard.

Behaviour:

- Enter a valid username and password, observe a 200 success response, and no error message in the console or on-screen. Unable to access any other path than:
  http://localhost:3000/admin/signin
- Enter a bad credential and get notice that the username or password are incorrect (indicates that the service is working)

It seems like the credentials are accepted based on the payload (which returns my password in plaintext and that feels weird). Is this a well-known issue tripping up a newbie? Or something different?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was an npm command line issue. Instead of using `npm start` I found `npm run dev` to work. For my development purpose, that resolves this issue. May come up on live, as I've seen it reported in the KeystoneJS Slack as well.

Comment: please pay attention when you do edits. You completely changed the meaning of the following answer with your edits making it wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557526/8620333 ... I don't know why you edits got approved ...