# Text within a colored box

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-decorations

I'm creating a simple HTML-CSS portfolio website. I'm struggling with finding a way to style the following text the way it is shown in the picture.

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

It is very important to note that I have achieved some results but the issue is that the text here is not centered left-to-right. It is more of a random alignment and I don't know how to achieve that. And also please do keep in mind that this text will be used in a way that it will be placed in front of a picture. So it has to be created as some sort of a component that I will be able to easily reuse/align later on with a picture.

Any ideas on how to achieve such results?

As you can see I have managed to add the text within a black box. But the second line doesn't look as in the prototype above. I don't know how to achieve this. Any ideas?

[image: Achieved results so far]

This is my code:

**HTML**

```css
/* Styles the header text "Hello, World!" putting it in a black box. */
   
.box {
   width: 50rem;
   margin: 0.2rem auto;
   font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
 }

 h1 {
   color: white;
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   line-height: 3rem; /* reduce size to remove gap between text */
   margin: 0px;
 }

 h1 span {
   background-color: #2d2d2d;
   padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
   padding-left: 1.2rem;
   padding-right: 1.2rem;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1rem 0px 0px #2d2d2d, -1rem 0px 0px #2d2d2d;
   box-shadow: 1rem 0px 0px #2d2d2d, -1rem 0px 0px #2d2d2d;
   -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
   -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
   -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
   box-decoration-break: clone;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Hello World Text that floats over the header picture -->
<div class="box">
  <h1>
   <span>Hello, <br> &emsp; World!</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use two elements instead of one? It's presentational after all not content.

Comment: Ideally the black box element will be 1 element and then the blue box text will be another one. These should float depending on the cursor's location. I don't want the "Hello, World!" to be treated as a two different elements because it may not look good when floating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text-indent can help you here instead of adding the space manually:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;    
  text-indent: -30px;
  margin:0;
  margin-left: 46px;
}

h1 span {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding: 0 1.2rem 0.8rem;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>Hello, <br> World!</span>
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the words into different span:

```css
h1 span{
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;    
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.world{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span class="hello">Hello,</span> <br>
    <span class="world">World!</span>
  </h1>
```